# Login in C# with connection to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, authentication

I'm trying to make a simple login in a website built in C#, but I can't connect to the database, if in the form's properties in the postbackurl I define where must go after login (`/inicio.aspx`), my app sends the user without check if that user and pass exists, if I don't put that, nothing happens.

In my class I have:

```
public DataSet sqlLogin(string usuario, string pass)//SOLO SE OCUPA 
{
    //SEOCUPA DATASERT YA QE NO SIRVE DATABALE Y EL DATASET SE LLENA CON ESE DATATABLE 
    string stSql = "select * from usuarios where usuario='"+usuario+"' and
pass='"+pass+"'";
    Bd miBd = new Bd();
    DataTable dt = miBd.sqlSelect(stSql);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    return ds;
}
```

in my form (in the button):

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClUsuario login = new ClUsuario();
    login.sqlLogin(txtUsuario.Text, txtPass.Text);

    try
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Inicio.aspx");
    }
    catch
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "usuario/password no validos";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get it to run, your code will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You can mitigate that by using parameterized commands instead of concatenating strings (the line starting with 'string stSql=...'). See here for some explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you must replace your code with this code

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClUsuario login = new ClUsuario();
    bool isAuthenticated = login.sqlLogin(txtUsuario.Text, txtPass.Text);
    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Inicio.aspx");
    }
    else    
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "usuario/password no validos";
    }
}


And return bool in your sqlLogin

try with this code 

if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   return true;
} 
return false;
```

Comment: thanks, in this moment I'm testing this code, but I have a question, I have to reeplace my code in the class for that code if(dt.Rows.Count...) ???? thanks in advance.

Comment: Happy to resolve your problem, Yes you can just replace with dt.Rows.Count, but if i take code with bool, authentification stay concept based on true or false.

Comment: in the class must be this way?   because I dont get it...  public DataSet sqlLogin(string usuario, string pass 
        string stSql = "select * from usuarios where usuario='"+usuario+"' and pass='"+pass+"'";
        Bd miBd = new Bd();
        DataTable dt = miBd.sqlSelect(stSql);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        return ds;
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
        {
            return true; 
        }
       return false; 
    }

Comment: remove `DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ds.Tables.Add(dt); return ds; `

Comment: Exactely, and if you have time, go to msdn, search data access with ADO.Net, in order to work for example with parameters in your service

Comment: But you must remove return ds, and modify your signature of method

Comment: yes `public DataSet sqlLogin` should be now `public boolean sqlLogin`

Comment: public bool IsAuthenticated(string usuario, string pass)
        {
            string query = "select * from usuarios where usuario='"+usuario+"' and pass='"+pass+"'";
            Bd miBd = new Bd();
            DataTable dt = miBd.sqlSelect(stSql);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try
{
    var ds = login.sqlLogin(txtUsuario.Text, txtPass.Text);
    if(ds.Tables[0].rows.count > 0) {
      Response.Redirect("/Inicio.aspx");
    }
    else {lblMsg.Text = "usuario/password no validos";}

}
catch
{
    lblMsg.Text = "Error Occurred!";
}
```

Also try to use sql parameters in your queries.

Comment: You should modify the catch-clause as it is now: the output it currently creates ("usuario/password no validos") is not correct, and it will only swallow useful exception information.